# Getting response code 500 while trying to connect to a URL to parse json data android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to connect to the Url and for that i am sending JSON data to the Url but i am getting response code 500 and I don't know where exactly the problem is .. I am trying to send URI data to get json data back from the URL

```
        package practise.c.practise;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Handler;
        import android.os.Message;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Base64;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;

        public class API extends AppCompatActivity {
            String USERID;
            String APIKEY;


            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_api);
                Log.d("oncreate", "onCreate: ");


                final Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                        .appendQueryParameter("day", "" + "1")
                        .appendQueryParameter("month", "" + "1")
                        .appendQueryParameter("year", "" +"2015" )
                        .appendQueryParameter("hour", "" + "1")
                        .appendQueryParameter("min", "" + "30")
                        .appendQueryParameter("lat", "" +"18.7250" )
                        .appendQueryParameter("lon", "" + "72.250")
                        .appendQueryParameter("tzone", "" + "5.5");

                Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        try {
                            Log.d("threadrun", "onCreate: ");
                            URL url = new URL("https://api.vehello.com/b1/birth_details");
                            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                            String userCredentials = "44463:6jjjjjjjjjjjjjf4447b59bfed";
                            String basicAuth = Base64.encodeToString(userCredentials.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT);
                            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization","Basic" + basicAuth);
                            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                            httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en");
                            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

                            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                            writer.write(query);
                            writer.flush();
                            writer.close();
                            os.close();
                            httpURLConnection.connect();


                            Log.d("responseerror", "run: "+httpURLConnection.getErrorStream());

                            int responseCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();


                            Log.d("responsecode", "run: "+responseCode);

                            if(responseCode == 200){

                                InputStream inputStr = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStr));
                                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                                String line;
                                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                    result.append(line);
                                }
                                Log.d("API:DATA", "run: "+result);

                            }



                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
                thread.start();





            }




        }
```

Comment: response code 500 usually means the fault is at the server side.

Comment: @ccsnoopy      code 500 means internal server error .. so the problem is with my code

Comment: as the name suggests, it is internal SERVER error, that means, unless your Android is the server, the problem is not on the android. That aside, if you use other devices (iOS, or web) does it throw the same error when you access it?

Comment: no it doesn't throws error from other devices

Comment: Who controls the server? Have him figure it out, he is to blame for the 500

Comment: haha i don't think so

Comment: I'm not joking. There is either an error in the logic on the server, or you sent a bad request and the server doesn't handle the error. Either way the fault is with the server

Comment: ohk thanks than i will concern with the person who handles the server